# Function returning reference not working with window.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, reference

```
1: #include <windows.h>

2: int& max(int& a, int& b)
3: {
4:   return a > b ? a : b;
5: }

6: int main()
7: {
8:   return 0;
9: }
```

Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition shouts:

1>e:...\main.cpp(2) : error C2062: type 'int' unexpected

1>e:...\main.cpp(2) : error C2062: type 'int' unexpected

1>e:...\main.cpp(2) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'

1>e:...\main.cpp(3) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

1>e:...\main.cpp(3) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

It seems to work if I replace windows.h with stdio.h or iostream (or if I remove it)

Why is this?

Comment: I'm guessing your `windows.h` is corrupted somehow. Did you happen to open it up in a text editor to look what's in it at some point? You might have mistakenly edited it.

Comment: windows.h has min and max macros.

Comment: Be very careful when returning references here – in 99% of the case this is *not* what you want (for instance with your code this wouldn’t work: `max(4, 5)`). Don’t be afraid to return by value, it’s efficient and will avoid making unnecessary copies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>

#undef min
#undef max

int & max(int& a, int& b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

`<windows.h>` defines macros for `max` and `min` which interfere with yours.

Other ways

- Rename your functions.
- use `NOMINMAX`. This is the common solution recommended  for using some STL headers which define min and max themselves.

  ```
  #define NOMINMAX
  #include <windows.h>
  ```

Comment: There is another (imho preferable) way: just define NOMINMAX before including windows.h (or use a compiler flag to add the definition). This will stop windows.h from defining both macros.

Comment: @ollb No. Apparently that fails under some circumstances (although I suspect that those circumstances are that it was forgotten somehow; defining it *via the compiler options* should be safe).

Comment: Well I personally never had a problem with `NOMINMAX` and I think it should be mentioned here. Also @user93353 as far as I know `WINDOWS_LEAN_AND_MEAN` won't include the effect of `NOMINMAX`.